# Toggle Opacity with HotKey in Terminal/iTerm

Tags: transparency, opacity, terminate, iterm2

Is there any way to set up a hotkey to change the opacity in either the terminal or iTerm? I usually use a low percentage opacity and it would be nice to be able to toggle on and off quickly.

EDIT: Cmd + U does essentially the same thing without some customizability

Comment: Thanks for the <D-u> note! I'll be using this one a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use AppleScript to do that.

i.e. in iTerm (ver. 2.9+) you can use the following to set all windows/sessons to 50% transparency:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    repeat with aWindow in windows
        tell aWindow
            tell current session
                set transparency to 0.5
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Save that to a file and run it from the cmd-line via:

```
osascript scriptname.scpt
```

You could also drop it into `Automator.app` and set it up to run via a Hot-key combo..

Assuming you can do the same in `Terminal.app`, open up the AppleScript Dictionary for it and look at setting window properties/transparency...

Comment: I get the following when trying your script in iTerm2: `execution error: iTerm got an error: Can’t set current session of item 1 of every window to 0.0. (-10006)` Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of iTerm are you using? I just retested it with `Build 2.9.20160206` and it works fine.

Comment: I am using version, 2.1.4 which is newest (this is iTerm2 not iTerm). `Cmd + U` works for me. I also set up the same for VIM (`Cmd+U`) so I can watch things in the background while I code.

Comment: You are using an the `old` version of iTerm2, the AppleScript that I listed is for newer (beta) 2.9.x version. http://iterm2.com/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.

Answer (score 20):

`cmd + u` toggles the transparency.

Comment: how do you enable this permanently?

Comment: Just go to iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Window .. and from there you can manage the transparency.